# KSQL EXTRACTJSONFIELD with JSON formatted messages returns null

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Using KSQL-CLI, with a kafka topic whose messages are JSON objects. I wish to extract fields such as obj.updaterId without declaring exhaustive STRUCT or MAP field definitions.

> ```
> {
>   "id": "5ba8f7e6b93c7964efb00f48",
>   "source": "ShareService",
>   "obj": {
>     "updaterId": "systems@test.com",
>     "desc": "foobar",
>     "name": "com.test.auto.sensor"
>   }
> }
> ```

I can create a Stream successfully in many ways, the simplest being:

```
CREATE STREAM objs1 (obj VARCHAR) WITH (kafka_topic='json-topic', value_format='JSON');
```

Simple select works as expected, you can see the contents of obj...

```
SELECT *  FROM objs1;
```

> 1537804190394 | "5ba8f7e6b93c7964efb00f48" | {name=com.test.auto.sensor,
>   updaterId=systems@test.com, desc=foobar}

What doesn't work here is any attempt to extract a JSON field from obj using EXTRACTJSONFIELD. The response to both top-level and nested objects is 'null'.

```
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(obj, '$.updaterId') AS updater FROM objs1;
```

> null

There is a note in [the ksql documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#scalar-functions) that says that if the data is an actual object in a STRING column that I COULD use STRUCT instead. It does not say that I MUST use STRUCT.

BTW, using STRUCT does work but, I am interested in EXTRACTJSONFIELD because the deep structures of my messages will vary. In other words, a null response will sometimes be expected if the messages does not contain the deep structure.

Works:

```
CREATE STREAM objs1 (obj STRUCT<updaterId VARCHAR>) WITH (kafka_topic='json-topic', value_format='JSON');
SELECT OBJ->updaterId AS updater FROM OBJS1;
```

I swear that I see other examples in other people's questions that seem to be working for similar arrangements. What am I missing?

Note: I have simplified my JSON for this post. It is larger and more nested IRL but this simpler example is accurate, I believe.

KSQL Version 5.0.0 on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a material change in the JSON parser [ksql issues #1562](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1562) in the latest release that strips the quotes from the JSON content in a VARCHAR column (as you can see from my example) which causes the JSON parser to fail to find that field name.

The issue suggests that STRUCT be used instead of EXTRACTJSONFIELD (as with my working example above).

This doesn't seem to fit my use-case because my deep field names may change. Will research more on that and update.

Comment: Hi Tim, you're right, I think you are hitting this issue. Let's track it in the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

[ksql issues #1562](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1562) has been resolved and you should be able to use `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` function as before. Note that you need to use the latest build from the master to have this feature now.